# How to display a pods age?

Tags: kubernetes, server, production

I am working on two servers, each with a number of pods. The first server is Validation Env and I can use kubernetes commands, but the second server is on Prod Env I do not have full rights. It is out of the question to get full rights on the last one.

So, I am doing a platform stability statistic and I need info about the last reset of pods. I can see the "Age" but I cannot use a screenshot in my statistic, so I need a command that outputs every pods age or the last reset.

P.S. Every night at 00:00 the pods are saved and archived in a separate folder.

Comment: This data is available in kube-state-metrics. Do you use Prometheus?

Comment: Which permissions you have on prod?  Is there a user for you? Tecnically, it is easy to create a script that'll get stats by cron and sends it to some location available to you. Do you have someone in a team that can install your cron-script on Prod Env for you?

Comment: I have "user-access". I do not use Prometheus and we can't install anything on server. I was thinking that grep command that searches for restart  lines might work, but it is too much data to go thru in the archive.

Comment: My bad, we have Prometheus:  2019-11-19 00:58:25,157 [INFO ] startup-0 c.o.c.a.StartUp - "prometheus-reporter-server" subsystem started successfully

Comment: @Rareshu , you told that you have no full rights on Prod. Am I right that you have at least any rights on Prod Kubernetes cluster? Is there are a person that can elevate your permissions there? Additionally, how exactly pods are saved and archived?

Comment: for my user name just says "user-access".  The access can, but will not be upgraded, as I am not on the server team. Meanwhile I found a solution using zgrep, you can check it as the last answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Get pods already gives you that info:

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                     READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-8pnzq   1/1     Running       0          36s
$ kubectl delete po nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-8pnzq
pod "nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-8pnzq" deleted
$ kubectl get po
NAME                     READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-67l8l   1/1     Running       0          4s
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

command:
`zgrep "All subsystems started successfully" 201911??/*ota*`

response:
`23:23:37,429 [INFO ] main c.o.c.a.StartUp - All subsystems started successfully`

P.S. "ota" is my pod's name.